# fscanf c programming wierd error

Tags: c, file, input, output, scanf

I am not new to programming, but I encountered this small problem and I can't seem to get it.
I want to read a file with dates and put them in another file with another format

**Input example**: 18.08.2015
**Output example**: 18-08-2015

Here is the code (dat1 has "r" permission and dat2 "w"):

```
char d[3];
char m[3];
char g[5];
while(fscanf(dat1,"%s.%s.%s\n",&d,&m,&g)==3)
{
    fprintf(dat2,"%s-%s-%s\n",d,m,g);
}
```

On the other hand, this works fine if I use [space] instead of a [dot] in the input file. 
(18 08 2015)

What am I missing? The solution has to be as simple as possible and with using fscanf, not fgetc or fgets, to be explained to students that are just beginning to learn C. Thanks.

Comment: `fscanf(dat1,"%2[0-9].%2[0-9].%4[0-9]\n", d, m, g)`

Comment: `%s` reads till the next (white)space.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY this is what I am going to use. Thanks

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, I thought is must be like that, but I didn't know for sure. Thanks, it's very useful.

Comment: @mkdavor: why don't you read the documentation? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf

Answer (score 2):

The `%s` pattern matches a sequence of non-white-space characters, so the first `%s` will gobble up the entire string.

Why use `char` arrays at all, why not int?

```
int d;
int m;
int g;
while(fscanf(dat1,"%d.%d.%d\n",&d,&m,&g)==3)
{
    fprintf(dat2,"%d-%d-%d\n",d,m,g);
}
```

The `%d` in fprintf will not output leading zeros though. You'll have to teach your students a little bit extra or leave it for extra credit.

Comment: I suggest `fprintf(dat2,"%02d-%02d-%04d\n",d,m,g);` to match zero-padding OP requirement.

Comment: I need %s because I need 08 in the output and not 8. I realize that I can use %02d, but I needed the solution with %s. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Since the scanf format `%s` reads up to the next whitespace character, it cannot be used for a string ending with a <kbd>.</kbd>. Instead use a character class: `%2[0-9]` or `%2[^.]`. (Change the 2 to the maximum number of characters you can handle, and don't forget that the [ format code does not skip whitespace, so if you want to do that, put a space before the format code.)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
  fscanf(dat1,"%s.%s.%s\n",&d,&m,&g)
```

to

```
  fscanf(dat1,"%[^.].%[^.].%[^.]\n",d,m,g);
```